# How to keep apps from being removed from recent apps list

Tags: recents-screen

With Android 7 (aka [nougat](/questions/tagged/nougat)), behavious of the recent apps list changed: instead of being "kept forever (until swiped out)", apps now get removed by whatever criteria (from my research it now "only shows the 5 last used tasks, and tasks used in the last 6 hours"), which is quite annoying. I found this question asked multiple times e.g. at Reddit or XDA, but no answer. With Android-7 and Xposed, one could use the [Recents auto-removal override](https://repo.xposed.info/module/andse.recentsoverride) module, but that stopped working around Android-10.

So with Android-10 and up (I'm on 11 now), how can I keep Android from "expiring" apps from the recent-apps-list? Is there some "hidden setting" or other way to modify this behavior? Any solutions (including those requiring root, Magisk, Xposed) are welcome.